# Inkscape doesn't remember previously opened files

Tags: inkscape

The "open recent" submenu in the "File" menu is always empty. How can I fix this? I'm using Inkscape 0.91 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel`?

Comment: You may want to try running inkscape from the command line to identify any errors or warnings that might provide some clue. I'd suspect either a permissions or ownership problem in the .config folder.

Comment: -rw------- 1 christian christian 1547 Dec  5 22:31 /home/christian/.local/share/recently-used.xbel

Comment: running inkscape from terminal starts inkscape and that is all

Answer (score 3):

I found the reason: if I switch off "record file and application usage"
I get rid of the recent files in the dash panel (thats what I want) and I still have the recent files in LibreOffice, Scribus or Blender. In Inkscape and Gimp on the other hand the recent files remain only until the next start of the computer.
To have the recent files in Inkscape or Gimp also the next day, I have to turn on "record file and application usage" and to check at least "documents" and "pictures". That works, but I have them also in the Unity Dash Panel (what I don't want).
So that's the reason, but not the solution.

Comment: "Record file and application usage" is in Ubuntu System Settings under "Privacy" by the way.